# can C# read in a xml file to change its gui at runtime

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am making an application that will generate and SQL scripts from a template and after taking input for different fields from the user.

There are many templates, so the GUI needs to adjust for the fields that the user will be filling out.

In the interest of keeping this scalable, I'd rather not hardcode the GUIs into the program, but would like have it read from an XML file and change based on the template the user has selected.

This is preferred because if a new template were to arise, then all that the program needs is a XML file that corresponds to the template. And the actual code does not need to be changed.
I have my eyes set on using C# for this, as I have good experiences using it. 
I am open to suggestions for other languages though.

Edit: This is a project for work, and I wanted to be sure that this is possible with C# before convincing my employers to expand into using C#.

Comment: Sure, you can do that with c#.

Comment: Of course that's possible. Why wouldn't it be? Can you describe problems you experience?

Comment: What you're looking for is called WPF. google it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this sort of thing by subclassing Windows.Forms.Form and adding a constructor to accept your XML file as a parameter.  Add a parser for your XML file that will interpret instructions for which labels and fields you want to add to a consistent form design (say, two columns with a label for field name on the left and the actual input field on the right, easily achievable by filling the form with a TableLayoutPanel).  You just need to lay out your design constraints from the beginning and stick to them.

This is essentially what visual studio does when you create a form through the designer anyway, so I'd suggest you start by creating an example form manually and just looking at the kind of code it places in the form's designer.cs file

Answer (score -1):

Any language can do that. It's more about design patterns than specific technologies.

If you meant writing a GUI only declaratively and with XML, though, then no. You'd have to write your own parsing and GUI assembling code.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "writing a GUI only declaratively and with XML"?

Comment: I mean telling the framework to render a form just by giving it a XML file as input. Like `Form f = new Form("pathToXml");` and expecting it to work. There is no class, at least none that I know of, that would do that... I may be somewhat rusty, though. But as far as I know, you'll have to write your own code to parse the XML, and based on what you get, adding the right controls to the right places.

Comment: @Renan Completely not true. WPF is XAML (XML) based, then you actually CAN grab a XAML file from disk and parse that into a useful UI with a `XAMLReader`.